# smtpd_client_restrictions for local mail and Google Gmail only

Tags: postfix, gmail

I'm using Gmail as a spam filter, whereby it forwards mail to hendry@example.com and I use mutt to read my email.

However hendry@example.com accepts mail from everyone currently, so I want to restrict what it accepts to just Google gmail servers. Any recipes for that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the restriction [check_client_access](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#check_client_access) for this purpose. But you'll need to know the IP address or at least an IP address range of GMail's SMTP hosts to make it work.

Comment: This is doable since gmail.com uses spf to list all the outgoing email servers.  However, the list of IPs is likely to change at any point so you'd need to be really careful there.